# How do I create array of arrays in PowerShell?

Tags: arrays, powershell

I want to create an array of arrays in PowerShell.

```
$x = @(
    @(1,2,3),
    @(4,5,6)
)
```

It works fine. However, sometimes I have only one array in the array list. In that situation, PowerShell ignores one of the lists:

```
$x = @(
    @(1,2,3)
)

$x[0][0] # Should return 1
Unable to index into an object of type System.Int32.
At line:1 char:7
+ $a[0][ <<<< 0]
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (0:Int32) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotIndex
```

How do I create an array of arrays, guaranteed it remains as a two-dimensional array even if the array has only one array item in it?

Comment: NB: Where using an array of arrays it seems that the placement of the comma also matters.  More info here: https://windowsserver.uservoice.com/forums/301869-powershell/suggestions/33859141-inconsistent-array-initialization-behaviour

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Adding a comma force to create an array:

```
$x = @(
    ,@(1,2,3)
)
```

Simple way:

```
$x = ,(1,2,3)
```

Comment: The magic comma strikes again! Why does powershell won't create array without comma?

Comment: A good article on the magic : http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2007/01/23/array-literals-in-powershell.aspx. The comma operator is the array construction operator in PowerShell

Comment: Of course, then for consistency of syntax, you would hope that this `@( ,@(1,2,3) ,@(4,5,6) )` would work... but it doesn't give you what you expect. Sigh.

Comment: Microsoft broke the link in the comment above. The new location is https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2007/01/23/array-literals-in-powershell/

Comment: these types of 'conveniences' in a language are just asking for trouble.