# Displaying Contents and Structure of an array

Tags: powershell

Displaying Contents and Structure of an array

```
PS C:\> $a = 1,2,3
PS C:\> $b = 4,5,6
PS C:\> $c = $a,$b
PS C:\> $c
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

`$c` is not an array of numbers, it's an array of arrays.  But when I display its contents, this structure is not visible.

Is there any built-in way to display the contents of an array such that the structure is preserved?  Perhaps something like this:

```
@( @(1, 2, 3), @(4, 5, 6) )
```

Comment: Your current code doesn't create an array of arrays. Powershell will "fix it for you", and make `$c` a single concatenated array.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11138288/how-to-create-array-of-arrays-in-powershell?rq=1

Comment: `Format-Custom -InputObject $c -Expand CoreOnly`

Comment: @Eris You are not right. OP code really create array of arrays.

Answer (score 2):

The **built-in way** to display is as ***PetSerAl*** answered in the comments is to use `Format-Custom` cmdlet. It formats the output using a default or customized view. Read more at [MSDN](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849966.aspx)

Code (as answered by PetSerAl) is:

```
Format-Custom -InputObject $c -Expand CoreOnly
```

In case you want the display in the format you have mentioned exactly, then you need to write your own PowerShell code snippet. Note that you can also write the same using Pipeline. I expanded in favor of readability.

```
$a = 1,2,3
$b = 4,5,6
$c = $a,$b

$arrayForDisplay = "@( "
foreach($array in $c)
{
    $arrayForDisplay += "@( "
    foreach($arrayelement in $array)
    {
        $arrayForDisplay += $arrayelement.ToString() + ","
    }

    $arrayForDisplay = $arrayForDisplay -replace ".$"
    $arrayForDisplay += " ), "
}
$arrayForDisplay = $arrayForDisplay.Trim() -replace ".$"
$arrayForDisplay += " )"

$arrayForDisplay
```