# Why Isn't This Counting Correctly | PowerShell

Tags: powershell, loops, foreach, powershell-ise

Right now, I have a CSV file which contains 3,800+ records. This file contains a list of server names, followed by an abbreviation stating if the server is a Windows server, Linux server, etc. The file also contains comments or documentation, where each line starts with "#", stating it is a comment. What I have so far is as follows.

```
$file = Get-Content .\allsystems.csv
$arraysplit = @()
$arrayfinal = @()
[int]$windows = 0

foreach ($thing in $file){
    if ($thing.StartsWith("#")) {
        continue
        }
    else {
        $arraysplit = $thing.Split(":")
        $arrayfinal = @($arraysplit[0], $arraysplit[1])
    }
}

foreach ($item in $arrayfinal){
    if ($item[1] -contains 'NT'){
        $windows++
    }
    else {
        continue
    }
}
$windows
```

The goal of this script is to count the total number of Windows servers. My issue is that the first "foreach" block works fine, but the second one results in "$Windows" being 0. I'm honestly not sure why this isn't working. Two example lines of data are as follows:

```
example:LNX

example2:NT
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$arrayfinal = @($arraysplit[0], $arraysplit[1])
```

This replaces the array for every run.

Changing it to `+=` gave another issue. It simply appended each individual element. I used this post's info to fix it, sort of forcing a 2d array: [How to create array of arrays in powershell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11138288/how-to-create-array-of-arrays-in-powershell).

```
$file = Get-Content .\allsystems.csv
$arraysplit = @()
$arrayfinal = @()
[int]$windows = 0

foreach ($thing in $file){
    if ($thing.StartsWith("#")) {
        continue
        }
    else {
        $arraysplit = $thing.Split(":")
        $arrayfinal += ,$arraysplit
    }
}

foreach ($item in $arrayfinal){
    if ($item[1] -contains 'NT'){
        $windows++
    }
    else {
        continue
    }
}
$windows
```

> 1

I also changed the file around and added more instances of both *NT* and other random garbage. Seems it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

if the goal is to count the windows servers, why do you need the array?

can't you just say something like

```
foreach ($thing in $file)
{
    if ($thing -notmatch "^#" -and $thing -match "NT") { $windows++ }
}
```

Comment: Further simplified: `-cmatch '^[^#].*?NT'`

Answer (score 0):

I'd avoid making another ForEach loop for bumping count occurrences. Your $arrayfinal also rewrites everytime, so I used ArrayList.

```
$file = Get-Content "E:\Code\PS\myPS\2018\Jun\12\allSystems.csv"
$arrayFinal = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList($null)

foreach ($thing in $file){
    if ($thing.StartsWith("#")) {
        continue
        }
    else {
        $arraysplit = $thing -split ":"
        if($arraysplit[1] -match "NT" -or $arraysplit[1] -match "Windows")
        {
            $arrayfinal.Add($arraysplit[1]) | Out-Null
        }
    }
}

Write-Host "Entries with 'NT' or 'Windows' $($arrayFinal.Count)"
```

I'm not sure if you want to keep 'Example', 'example2'... so I have skipped adding them to arrayfinal, assuming the goal is to count "NT" or "Windows" occurrances

Answer (score 0):

> The goal of this script is to count the total number of Windows servers.

I'd suggest the easy way: using cmdlets built for this.

```
$csv = Get-Content -Path .\file.csv |
    Where-Object { -not $_.StartsWith('#') } |
    ConvertFrom-Csv

@($csv.servertype).Where({ $_.Equals('NT') }).Count

# Compatibility mode:
# ($csv.servertype | Where-Object { $_.Equals('NT') }).Count
```

Replace `servertype` and `'NT'` with whatever that header/value is called.