# Why does the new line change semantics in PowerShell multi-dimensional array creation?

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0

PowerShell [array of arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11138351/868975):

```
[string[][]] $array = @(
  ,@('one', 'two')
  ,@('three', 'four')
)
$array.ForEach({$_.GetType().Name, $_.Length, ($_ -join '-')})
```

The result is, as expected :

```
String[]  # first item is a string array
2         # has 2 elements
one-two   # one and two
String[]  # second item is a string array
2         # has 2 elements
three-four# three and four
```

But if we do not separate the arrays with a new line :

```
[string[][]] $array = @(
  ,@('one', 'two'), @('three', 'four')
)
```

The output becomes:

```
String[] # there are still 2 arrays
1        # but the first one has now only 1 element
one two  # the two expected elements got concatenated into 1
String[] # second array is ok
2
three-four
```

Why is that ?
<sub>PSVersion 5.1.18298.1000</sub>

Comment: remove the first comma on your second example

Comment: @MikeTwc without the comma it behaves erratically when there is only 1 array

Comment: The empty element yields in an empty string in the $array.ForEach... hence "" + @("x","y") returns "x y"

Comment: ok. probably it's a better idea to use arraylist then (adding new tuples with add method)

Comment: `$array = @('one', 'two'), @('three', 'four')`

Comment: @Bax When you want to create an array from a single element (that element being an array itself) you must use the unary array construction operator (`$array = ,@('a', 'b')`). Otherwise you must not use it (`$array = @('a', 'b'), @('c', 'd')`.