# Create an array of enumerable collections using ForEach-Object over object properties (without expanding / enumerating them)

Tags: powershell, powershell-cmdlet

I have a `Match[]` from string matching, each `Match` has a `Groups` property which is a `GroupCollection`. I want to map the `Match[]` to a `GroupCollection[]`, and I'm trying to do this with a pipeline's output using `ForEach-Object`.

The issue is that whenever I access and return `Match[x].Groups` in the script block, the collection gets enumerated and outputted as its contents, essentially expanding and flattening the `GroupCollection`'s and losing any instance properties.

Is there a way to pull this off with an pipeline output? Maybe `ForEach-Object` isn't the right function to use.

```ini
$String = "12345"
$Regex = "(?<number>\d)"
$MatchArr = ($String | Select-String  -Pattern $Regex -AllMatches).Matches # Match[]

$DesiredOutput = $MatchArr[0].Groups, $MatchArr[1].Groups, $MatchArr[2].Groups # etc..
Get-Member -InputObject $DesiredOutput[0] # "GroupCollection" 

$WrongOutput = $MatchArr | ForEach-Object {$_.Groups} # Resolves and outputs the collection contents, making a flat array of all the contents
Get-Member -InputObject $WrongOutput[0] # "Match"  $WrongOutput[0] == $MatchArr[0].Groups[0], AKA the actual contents
```

Answer (score 0):

While writing the question and including an iterative solution involving appending the collections to an array (still too long), the collections were still being enumerated when appended with `+=`, leading me down a search where I came across *that* problem's solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11138288/how-do-i-create-array-of-arrays-in-powershell), **which can also be adapted to the original `ForEach-Object` pipeline**.

The solution is to wrap the collection in an array which *then* gets resolved and enumerated instead, returning the collection itself. [To create an array from an array, we need to use the **comma operator**.](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/array-literals-in-powershell/) (Article linked in the SO answer I found).

```ini
$String = "12345"
$Regex = "(?<number>\d)"
$MatchArr = ($String | Select-String  -Pattern $Regex -AllMatches).Matches # Match[]

$Groups = $MatchArr | ForEach-Object {,$_.Groups}
Get-Member -InputObject $Groups[0] # "GroupCollection", Nice
```